# Change the div background when onmouseover another div

Tags: javascript, css

I have DIV1 and when user onmouserover it, I want to change the background of DIV2 (different part of the webpage), how to do that, please? And when the user onmouseout DIV1, then DIV2 should get back as it was before.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just regular javascript?

Comment: Have you tried Google? Please read the FAQ before posting.

Comment: you can do it by ul & li and only with css without javascript

Answer (score 4):

You could alternatively do it with CSS and the general sibling selector (`~`), or some combination of other selectors to specify the `div` you want to change.

```
.one:hover ~ .two {background:salmon;}
```

or

```
.one:hover ~ ul .three {background: lightblue;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N5zkU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to bind mouse events in pure `JavaScript`.

```
document.getElementById('XYZ').onmouseover = function(){
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/W74k3/) of a `div` changing a CSS property of another `div` on `mouseover`.

Comment: Hi, any idea what I'm doing wrong here: www.gemiusinfo.cz/222index.html  ? :/

Comment: I would suggest putting it in an anonymous auto-executing function at the end of your `HTML` document. `(function(){ //Your code here })()`.

Comment: Also, @bookcasey's solution is easier, faster, and supports IE7+ with the ~ sibling selector in `CSS`; `.one:hover ~ .two {background:salmon;}`

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have this html

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

And this css:

```
 .div2 {
    background: #FFF url(/path/to/mouseOUTImage) top left no-repeat;
 }
 .div2MouseOver {
    background: #FFF url(/path/to/mouseOVERImage) top left no-repeat;
 }
```

Then using jQuery you can do:

```
$('.div1')
.mouseenter(function() {
  $('.div2').addClass('div2MouseOver');
})
. mouseleave(function() {
  $('.div2').removeClass('div2MouseOver');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use plain JS to implement what you need,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WWLKa/1/)

```
(function () {

    //change the value of div1 with your first div box
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1'); 
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    var defBC = div2.style.backgroundColor;

    addEventHandler(div1, 'mouseover', function () {
        div2.style.backgroundColor= 'black';
    });

    addEventHandler(div1, 'mouseout', function () {
        div2.style.backgroundColor= defBC;
    });


    function addEventHandler(el, eType, handler) {
        if (el.addEventListener) { // W3C, FF  
            el.addEventListener(eType, handler, false);
        } else if (el.attachEvent) { // IE  
            el.attachEvent('on' + eType, function() {
                handler.call(el);
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accept using jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
var bgcolor;
$("#id_of_first_div").hover(function(){
      bgcolor = $("#id_of_div_2").css('backgroundColor');
      $("#id_of_div_2").css('backgroundColor', '#ffcc00'); 
   },
   function(){
      $("#id_of_div_2").css('backgroundColor', bgcolor);
});
```